# How do I apply a command to every line in a selection in Vim and replace with the result (like a spreadsheet)?

Tags: vim

I have a table of values (actually written in LaTeX markup) and I can select one column only using `Ctrl+Q`

For example,

```
% Select the second column only ....
1.75130211563   & 0.0299693961831 \\
1.72144412106   & 0.0181406611688 \\
1.92102386609   & 0.0247758598737 \\
1.56512790839   & 0.0137107006809 \\
1.75263937567   & 0.017155656704  \\
1.99501744437   & 0.39550649953   \\
1.96862597164   & 0.030198328601  \\
...
```

I'd like to reduce the number of decimal places of the selected numbers only (i.e. for each number selected I apply `round(NUMBER * 100)/100` to get, for example, the number rounded to 2 decimal places). To do this, I need to first have a variable to refer to `NUMBER` (the number on that line) as well as replace the current selection with the output.

How do I do this?

Also if this isn't possible, I can copy the column into an actual spreadsheet program and edit it there, but how do I paste it back in place?

**Update:** I've accepted an answer. It isn't as neat as I had hoped, but it does make sense. Thanks!

**Another update:** To paste a column in from an external spreadsheet, paste the column into a `:new` buffer, select the data using `Ctrl+Q` and yank into a register. Move to the top line and appropriate column in the table of data and paste in with `P`.

Comment: Can you update your question with an example of how the actual text looks like? BTW, the `rccol` package can do rounding directly in LaTeX, see [rccol](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/rccol/rccol.pdf)

Comment: Ah thanks, that's good to know. However I'm keen to see if Vim can handle this neatly since this type of task has cropped up outside of editing LaTeX documents.

Comment: See `:h :normal-range`, `:h expand()` (and `:h <cWORD>`), `:h t`, `:h printf()` (you can use `printf("%.2f", number)` to print `number` with two digits after decimal dot).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for this ?

```
:'<,'>s#\%V\d*\.\d\+#\=round(str2float(submatch(0))*100)/100#g
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this is used, when I select a visual block and then hit `:` to enter commands, `'<,'>` is automatically inserted. Writing the above afterwards causes an error, replacing the command with the above cause the whole document to be affected...

Comment: `%` above means whole file, remove that and go for the visual selection markers only i.e. `'<,'>`

Comment: To restrict to the visual block you also need to include `\%V` in the search field: `:'<,'>s#\%V\(\d*\.\d\+\)#\=round(str2float(submatch(1))*100)/100#g` (otherwise all occurences on selected lines will be substituted).

Comment: I've edited the answer to include Prince Goulash's suggestion - it now works great.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
:'<,'>:s/\d\+\.\d\+/\=printf("%.2f", str2float(submatch(0)))/
```

I.e. visually select the first column and issue the command above.

```
% Select the second column only ....
1.75   & 0.0299693961831 \\
1.72   & 0.0181406611688 \\
1.92   & 0.0247758598737 \\
1.57   & 0.0137107006809 \\
1.75   & 0.017155656704  \\
2.00   & 0.39550649953   \\
1.97   & 0.030198328601  \\
```

Comment: This kind of works, unfortunately tabs seem to mess things up a bit in the actual file I am editing. I have set a large `tabstop` so that columns do not overlap and the selection is only numbers (i.e. no spaces etc.), however the above command for some reason fails on rows where the previous columns values are quite wide (i.e. enough to cause a column to overlap if the `tabstop` was slightly smaller). Is Vim reading the selection information using `shiftwidth` or something?

Comment: Vim is not selecting anything based on shiftwidth.  You can see what Vim is selecting by yanking your selection and pasting it into a blank area of the document.  If that doesn't help you figure it out perhaps you could post a problematic table.